# Tips on how to improve this Guess the Number game code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried many ways to improve it, but as a beginner I was only able to achieve the result with the following code. As well, I noticed that if I type a non-integer value after passing the while verification it breaks the program... I would really appreciate any tips on how to improve my code. Thank you very much!

```
# Generates a cryptographically secure number
import secrets

# SystemRandom instance from secrets module
number_generator = secrets.SystemRandom()

number = number_generator.randint(1, 10)

# The following code is used to print the generated number: print("The random number is", number)

print('Please, guess a number between 1 and 10')

# Asks the user for input and checks if it is an integer number
while True:
    user_number = input('Your number is: ')
    try:
        user_number = int(user_number)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please, input only integer numbers between 1 and 10!')
        continue

while number != user_number:
    print('Please, select another number!')
    user_number = int(input())
    if user_number > number:
        print('Too high!')
    elif user_number < number:
        print('Too low!')
    else:
        print('Awesome! The number is correct!')
        break
```

Comment: looks good to me, are you looking for a shorter version, you could combine your two while statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code which I made a few days ago.

```
import random

def _input(message, type=int):
    while True:
        try:
            return type(input(message))
        except:
            print("Please enter valid" , type.__name__)

n = random.randint(1,99)

print("Computer has selected a number")
guess = _input("Enter your guess: ")

while 1:
    if n < int(guess):
        print("\nGuess is bigger than number")
        guess = _input("Enter your guess again: ")
    elif n > int(guess):
        print("\nGuess is smaller than number")
        guess = _input("Enter your guess again: ")
    else:
        print("\nThats correct!!!")
        break
```

I made a function to check for entered number to be int.
In function I made a try catch block to handle the error which is caused due to entering string.
If you can't understand something in code tell me

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, you were able to make it work using a smaller code!

Answer (score 0):

1) In the second loop you are not validating the input, which explains why it fails if the input is not an int.

2) You are asking for a number between 1 and 10, but you do not validate it's in that range.

This applies those two changes:

```
while True:
    try:
        user_number = int(input('Your number is: '))
        if 10 >= user_number >= 1:
            break
        print('Please, input only integer numbers between 1 and 10!')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please, input only integer numbers between 1 and 10!')

while number != user_number:
    try:
        user_number = int(input('Please, select another number!'))
        if not 10 >= user_number >= 1:
            print('Please, input only integer numbers between 1 and 10!')
            continue        
    except ValueError:
        print('Please, input only integer numbers between 1 and 10!')
        continue
    if user_number > number:
        print('Too high!')
    elif user_number < number:
        print('Too low!')
    else:
        print('Awesome! The number is correct!')
        break
```

It could have been nicer and shorther if you would write a function that validates the input, so it wouldn't be written in both loops, but since I don't know if you are already using UDF's, I didn't use it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the code works perfectly! I did not know about UDF's until now, I will study it!

Answer (score -1):

```
# Generates a cryptographically secure number
import random
number = random.randint(1, 10)

print('Please, guess a number between 1 and 10')

# Asks the user for input and checks if it is an integer number

def func():
    while True:

        user_number = input('Your number is: ')
        try:
            user_number = int(user_number)
            if 10 <= user_number <= 1:
                print('Please, input only integer numbers between 1 and 10!')
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print('Please, input only integer numbers between 1 and 10!')
            continue

        while number != user_number:
            print('Please, select another number!')
            user_number = int(input())
            if user_number > number:
                print('Too high!')
            elif user_number < number:
                print('Too low!')
            else:
                print('Awesome! The number is correct!')
                return

func()
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Unfortunately, it does not work. I experience the same error when inputing using your code...

Comment: `random.randint()` doesn't generate a cryptographically secure number. The OP imported `secrets` instead, which *does*.